# How to set IEqualityComparer for test parameters from another class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

i am doing Unit test to compare list value. For this I used IEqualityComparer.

Here is my IEqualityComparer class.

```
public class KeyValueEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValue<TKey, TValue> x, KeyValue<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

        return x.Key == y.Key && x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValue<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;

        int hashCodeName = obj.Key == null ? 0 : obj.Key.GetHashCode();
        int hasCodeAge = obj.Value.GetHashCode();

        return hashCodeName ^ hasCodeAge;
    }
}
```

and this is KeyValue class:

```
 public class KeyValue<TKey, TValue>
{
    public KeyValue()
    {
    }

    public KeyValue(TKey k, TValue v)
    {
        Key = k;
        Value = v;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

i am trying to use TKey and Tvalue as a parameter inside IEqualityComparer.then i can pass different data types through this class. But the problem is i can't use parameters inside the IEqualityComparer interface. please tell me a way to do this.

Comment: KeyValue<int, string>(), KeyValue<string, string>()
This way i want to pass my list values. sometime my list has int and string other time it has only strings.

Comment: The class must also be generic: `public class KeyValueEqualityComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>>`. But you can't use `==` which any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your class to derive from a generic interface without using concrete types, your class has to be generic as well:

```
public class KeyValueEqualityComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValue<TKey, TValue>>
```

Since it isn't guaranteed that `TKey` and `TValue` can be compared via the `==` operator (see [Compiler Error CS0019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019)) you will have to use the `Equals` method for the comparison:

```
public bool Equals(KeyValue<TKey, TValue> x, KeyValue<TKey, TValue> y)
{
   if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

   if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

    return x.Key.Equals(y.Key) && x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
}
```